# Redondear y quitar 0 en un procedimiento almacenado en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado con los siguientes datos.

`T.UNIT`: valor que me muestra es 125.000 quisiera volverlo a 125.

`CUNIT`: .055555 Lo que quiero: 0.056

El procedimiento es el siguiente:

```
SELECT DCA.PRODUCTO,SUM(VALOR) T_UNIT,SUM(VALOR)/
(SELECT  DV.PESO FROM VENTA.DETALLE_PRODUCTO_VENTA DV WHERE ID_DOCUMENTO=@ID_DOCUMENTO AND DV.PRODUCTO=DCA.PRODUCTO) CUNIT
FROM VENTA.DOCUMENTO_COSTOS_ADICIONALES DCA       
INNER JOIN VENTA.COSTOS_ADICIONALES CA ON DCA.ID_COSTOSADICIONAL=CA.ID_COSTOADICIONAL 
WHERE DCA.ID_DOCUMENTO=@ID_DOCUMENTO AND PRODUCTO <>'TODOS'
GROUP BY DCA.PRODUCTO
order by PRODUCTO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para este tipo de redondeos te recomiendo hacer uso de [`CAST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) para convertir los valores a los deseados de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT
    DCA.PRODUCTO,
    CAST(SUM(VALOR) AS DECIMAL(8)) T_UNIT,
    CAST(SUM(VALOR) / (
        SELECT DV.PESO
        FROM VENTA.DETALLE_PRODUCTO_VENTA DV
        WHERE
            ID_DOCUMENTO=@ID_DOCUMENTO
            AND DV.PRODUCTO=DCA.PRODUCTO
    ) AS NUMERIC(8,3)) CUNIT
FROM VENTA.DOCUMENTO_COSTOS_ADICIONALES DCA
INNER JOIN VENTA.COSTOS_ADICIONALES CA
    ON DCA.ID_COSTOSADICIONAL=CA.ID_COSTOADICIONAL 
WHERE
    DCA.ID_DOCUMENTO=@ID_DOCUMENTO
    AND PRODUCTO <>'TODOS'
GROUP BY DCA.PRODUCTO
ORDER BY PRODUCTO
```

La conversión a [`NUMERIC(8,3)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fixed-point-types.html) usará 8 cifras enteras y 3 decimales. Y `NUMERIC(8)` (al igual que `NUMERIC(8,0)`) usará solo 8 cifras enteras. También podrías haber usado [`INT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html) u otros tipos de datos similares.

Answer (score 0):

Existen una función llamada **round()** en MySQL para redondearlo siempre hacia arriba añádelo

```
SELECT DCA.PRODUCTO,ROUND(SUM(VALOR),0) T_UNIT,SUM(VALOR)/
(SELECT ROUND(DV.PESO,4) FROM VENTA.DETALLE_PRODUCTO_VENTA DV WHERE ID_DOCUMENTO=@ID_DOCUMENTO AND DV.PRODUCTO=DCA.PRODUCTO) CUNIT
FROM VENTA.DOCUMENTO_COSTOS_ADICIONALES DCA       
INNER JOIN VENTA.COSTOS_ADICIONALES CA ON DCA.ID_COSTOSADICIONAL=CA.ID_COSTOADICIONAL 
WHERE DCA.ID_DOCUMENTO=@ID_DOCUMENTO AND PRODUCTO <>'TODOS'
GROUP BY DCA.PRODUCTO
order by PRODUCTO;
```

Te coloco dos imágenes de como funciona, saludos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te haya servido.